# Joomla turns image into Read:more link

Tags: image, joomla, blogs

I got a problem with *Joomla*. I created a `MenuItemType` Category `Blog` which perfectly lists all the articles of a single category. Nevertheless I got a problem when I create an article for the category. Joomla automatically turns all images into `readmore` links. For instance

```
<p>
<img alt="" src="image.JPG" style="width: 180px; height: 79px;" />
</p>
```

will turn into

```
<a href="/index.php/en/news/24-zweite-news" title="Read more: Zweite News">
  <img src="image.JPG" width="180" height="79"  class="multithumb_blog" style="border: ;" alt="Read more: Zweite News">
</a>
```

I cannot find any **configuration parameter to change this behaviour**.

Comment: Is this the intro image maybe? Also what version of joomla are you using?

Comment: No the intro image is not set.I am using Joomla! 3.1.5 Stable

Comment: What template are you using, is it based on a framework like T3, Gantry etc…

Comment: Please list any third party plugins you have installed and enabled, and with the template name

Comment: Hi I ended up installing a clean version and reentering the content since it wasnt that much. I also suppose that some plugin was responsible for that.